# What does the client do in Command Pattern?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

[image]I am reading the headfirst design patterns book. 
I observe that the client is shown analogous to a hotel customer, who creates an `order(command)` object, the `waitress(invoker)` picks it and calls its `execute()` method which in turn calls the chef's `cook() method(chef=receiver)`
In the command pattern class diagram, I can see client is associated with `Receiver` as well as the `ConcreteCommand` class. I am unable to get the example because in real world, a customer is not supposed to know about the cook and set the instructions for him. Other concern is that in the command pattern class diagram, I observe that Client is not shown associated with Invoker, but in the attached java program I can see the Invoker reference in the Client class.
Totally confused about what Client module does in the command pattern. Clear about the rest 4 modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html

> Client creates a ConcreteCommand object and sets its receiver [...] The Client asks for a command to be executed.

It even has sample code that show *what* the client does:

> The client creates some orders for buying and selling stocks (ConcreteCommands). Then the orders are sent to the agent (Invoker). [...]
>
> ```
> public class Client {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         StockTrade stock = new StockTrade();
>         BuyStockOrder bsc = new BuyStockOrder (stock);
>         SellStockOrder ssc = new SellStockOrder (stock);
>         Agent agent = new Agent();
>
>         agent.placeOrder(bsc); // Buy Shares
>         agent.placeOrder(ssc); // Sell Shares
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> [image: picture]

Comment: As per your example, 
StockTrade is the receiver.
BuyStockOrder is a ConcreteCommand.
Agent is the invoker.

Client class is associated to all three of them

But according to the class diagram attached above Client does not know about the Invoker, i.e. the Agent.
Still confused

Comment: So you're confused because the diagram doesn't show a "calls" association between Client and Agent, where the client code calls the `placeOrder()` method? Yeah, it does seem to be missing from these diagrams.

Comment: yes, but i saw the same diagram in the book as well, so confused if i am missing something

Comment: You're not. The diagram is. If it has a line from Client to StockTrade, a similar line should exist from Client to Agent. In real (non-sample) code, both Receiver (StockTrade / Cook) and Invoker (Agent / Waiter) would exist prior to Client (Customer) arriving on the scene, so they would be obtained through means other than `new`.

Comment: Agreed to that. What I was thinking is that client is not going to talk to invoker, that code can be a part of invoker or some business class.Client is just responsible for creating the ConcreteCommand and setting the actual receiver in it. Invoker can execute the command at a later time once that wiring is done. Here they wanted to create a single demo program and hence assimilated all the stuff into a single program.

Answer (score 2):

You've stumbled upon the challenge with demonstrating design patterns with analogy, by a single concrete example, or with object diagrams. Except for very simple patterns, the concepts and examples usually don't map perfectly to all useful instances of the pattern.

I highly recommend that you pick several sources to learn any of the more complex design patterns. Every explanation is going to have strengths and weaknesses, and you'll probably get a more accurate picture if you take several viewpoints into account. There are plenty of free sources available on the Internet, so you probably don't need to buy additional books (except, eventually, [the original Design Patterns book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), for reference purposes).

What isn't clear in the diagram is that the `Client`, the `Invoker`, and the `Receiver` are abstract concepts, and don't have a single form that always applies in every case. In any particular implementation of the command pattern, most of these roles are going to be present (except maybe the `Receiver` - it is possible that the command is self-contained). You may even be able to point out a specific bit of code that maps to each of these roles, but it's going to map differently in every application. It may even map differently in separate parts of the same application.

There are parts of the diagram you shared that I have problems with, because they are not always true. The `Client` might not directly access or even know about the `Receiver`. The `Client` might also not know about specific `ConcreteCommand` objects. The `Client` might know how to ask for an instance of a command, and it might know some information that helps pick the right command. However, the client might in some cases be oblivious to which `ConcreteCommand` object was executed, especially if you combine the command pattern with [the `AbstractFactory` pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

> in real world, a customer is not supposed to know about the cook and set the instructions for him

Analogies and models tend to break down or become confusing when you compare them strictly to reality. It is best to try to figure out what the model is trying to accomplish, and which possible interpretation of reality that the model is trying to account for.

Also, not all models/analogies are any good :) Sometimes they don't actually get the job done.

> I observe that Client is not shown associated with Invoker

This is perfectly valid in some implementations of the pattern. The code that eventually calls `execute()` may not be the same code that is capable of accepting actions.

The diagram may show a single box, but in the restaurant analogy, the waiter, the cooks, the busboys, the host, the cashier, etc, are all a part of that `Invoker` role.

The problem with the diagram is that the client eventually has to pass the command off to the invoker. The invoker itself might have a way to accomplish this, or there may be some sort of system in between (like a command queue). Either way, in their explanation, the invoker role handles both things, and the client must therefore know about the invoker.

Finally:

> What does the client do in Command Pattern?

- The `Client` is responsible for knowing that it wants a command to be done
- The `Client` is responsible for knowing how to pick which command gets done, and get an instance of it (even if the client delegates the actual construction of that `ConcreteCommand` to some other part of the system)
- The `Client` is responsible for knowing how to pass off a command so that it will eventually be invoked (passing it to some object in the `Invoker` role, even if that command eventually gets passed off to some other object that actually calls `execute()`)
- The `Client` is responsible for actually handing off the command to the `Invoker` (whether it is directly handed off, or passed off to some intermediate part of the system first)

Answer (score 0):

So the idea of a client is in opposition to the idea of a server. (for get the restaurant metaphor for a minute). The server is the centralized application, the client is the interface presented on a users machine. The client machine or GUI signals wither a receiver (middle man) or your program directly to make things happen.

I hope this makes things a little clearer.